# How to alter custom Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I will like to alter this custom Makefile, in order to Debug with NetBeans IDE.

Im able to clean , build , and run but not Debug.

NetBeans IDE expects the Debug executable in /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test.

**Here is the Makefile:**

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall
#executable 
EXE = main

#debug flags
DBGCFLAGS = -DDEBUG -g
DBGCXXFLAGS = -DDEBUG -g

#release flags 
RELEASE_PROGRAM = dist/
DEBUG_PROGRAM = dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test/

#source  files 
SOURCES_C = $(wildcard *.c) 
SOURCES_CC = newmain.cpp 

#object files 
OBJS = $(SOURCES_C:%.c=%.o) $(SOURCES_CC:%.cpp=%.o)
    
#libraries 
LIBS = -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -lxerces-c

debug: $(DEBUG_PROGRAM)$(EXE)
    
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(DEBUG_PROGRAM)$(EXE): $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#targets 
all: $(RELEASE_PROGRAM)$(EXE)
    
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(RELEASE_PROGRAM)$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    
clean:
    rm -rf $(RELEASE_PROGRAM) $(OBJS)
    rm -rf $(DEBUG_PROGRAM) $(OBJS)
    mkdir $(RELEASE_PROGRAM)
    mkdir -p $(DEBUG_PROGRAM)
```

**(I want to run debug via IDE, to setup easy breakpoints) Running "debug" via NetBeans GUI , outputs this message then error:**

cd '/home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'

/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug

gmake: `debug' is up to date.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2ms)

***Error:***

/home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test does not exist or is not an executable.

**Running Make from the command line:**

make clean debug

```
rm -rf dist/  newmain.o
rm -rf dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test/  newmain.o
mkdir dist/
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test/
g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall newmain.cpp
newmain.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
newmain.cpp:37:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     char* xmlFile = "/home/myuser/sample_pds4_files/for_ary/A0087_0008_597249118_597252671_181130002623_eu.xml";
                     ^
newmain.cpp: In function ‘void parse_dom(xercesc_3_1::DOMNode*)’:
newmain.cpp:120:19: warning: unused variable ‘dom_node_list’ [-Wunused-variable]
     DOMNodeList * dom_node_list = NULL;
                   ^
g++ -DDEBUG -g -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test/main  newmain.o -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -lxerces-c
```

I havent set any points via gdb & want to use NetBeans IDE so running via command line is useless for me.

IDE expects the debug executable to be in the path "/home/myuser/NetB
eansProjects/SOFF_test/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test".

**How can I alter this custom Makefile in a minimal way in order to be able to Debug(use GUI breakpoints/debug points) via the NetBeans IDE???**

Thanks a Million!

Comment: What do `sudo` rights have to do with anything?  You should not be trying to build software in a directory you do not own, and if you own it then you shouldn't need special privileges to make arbitrary directory trees within it.

Comment: `-o $(DEBUG_PROGRAM)` looks wrong. Try changing it to `-o $@` and see what happens.

Comment: 1) Your Makefile is inconsistent, compare the recipes for the release and the debug executable. -- 2) Make Netbeans build the debug target with `make debug`, which you can also try on the command line to check it.

Comment: @Beta, i got same error. See updated Makefile.

Comment: @thebusybee, I attempted to make it more consistent. Any suggestions?

Comment: The output you show list two different paths, one starting with `/home/myuser/` and one starting wth `/home/anaim/`. Is that a typo in your question? -- You could check by hand whether the executable exists that Netbeans expects. -- Compare the recipes, dude: `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^` and `$(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)` are *not* consistent. -- I'm not using Netbeans, but there should be an option to run `make debug`, which is does not yet. It runs `/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug`.

Comment: @thebusybee, yes that was a typo

Comment: I am not a NetBeans user, but the error message says that 'soff_test' is expected to be an executable but it is not found. From the Makefile it seems that soff_test is supposed to be a directory while the executable should have the name 'main'. Maybe you could check the NetBeans settings for the Debug run?

Comment: @rhaport has almost certainly given the correct approach, but I must ask: why don't you *build* the debug executable by means of Make on the command line, and then *run* it by means of NetBeans?